Replace row values after a certain string pattern in R using stringr
I have a data frame in R called df:

name=c("john","mary","stef","paul","helen")
var =c("[1127] pizza" ,                                                                          
 "[1000ui] berger"   ,                                        
 "[5748A!] pasta" ,                                        
 "[8245A&] sweet" ,       
 "[9893] drink" )
df=tibble(name,var);df


Resulting to:
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  name  var            
  <chr> <chr>          
1 john  [1127] pizza   
2 mary  [1000ui] berger
3 stef  [5748A!] pasta 
4 paul  [8245A&] sweet 
5 helen [9893] drink   

I want to remove in the column var the string that is in each row value [...] and keep the rest. Ideally I want the data frame (tibble) to look like this:



name
var




john
pizza


mary
berger


stef
pasta


paul
sweet


helen
drink



How can I achieve it using string package in R or other in tidyverse functions?
Take into account that after the food the string continues with more than 5 words.Example “[1127] pizza is the best delivery food” and to extract the whole string text without the [1127].

With your specific case try df$var <- gsub("\\[.*\\] *", "", df$var).

I think this is a good use case for word function from stringr package:
update for more words:
library(stringr)
library(words)

df %>%    
  mutate(var = word(var,start = 2L, end = -1))

first answer:
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(var = word(var,2))

  name  var   
  <chr> <chr> 
1 john  pizza 
2 mary  berger
3 stef  pasta 
4 paul  sweet 
5 helen drink 


If after each food there was any more text ?I want to include that text.So word function will still be a good case?

Yes you can still use word. like: df %>%    mutate(var = word(var,start = 2L, end = -1)),

@HomerJaySimpson this will only work if the you are guaranteed to discard the first word. Otherwise, I will suggest to use the option given in the comments above. eg sub('.*?\\]', '', df$var) or str_remove(df$var, ".*?\\]")
